# случайным образом нужно выбрать 4 элемента из списка чтобы они НЕ ПОВТОРЯЛИСЬ, есть ли такая возможность?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

lots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

random_index = len(lots) * random.randint(4, 4) // 15
print("The winner of lotery need to have this index:")
print(random.choices(lots, k=random_index))
```

Оно работает, но иногда выходят два одинаковых индекса, а не хотелось бы. Спасибо большое!

Comment: [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 4):

Я все понял у `choices()` и есть свойство повторяться.

Вот простое решение:

```
import random

lots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print(random.sample(lots, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это.

```py
import random

lots = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
result = set()

while len(result) < 4:
    my_index = lots[random.randint(0, len(lots) - 1)]

for i in result:
    print("The winner of lotery need to have this index:", i)
```